# Is there a way to use a flag variable in a template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm looping through a result set and when a certain condition is met I want to run through a conditional statement.  After that condition has been met I want to continue looping through the result set without running through that condition.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could go about this?

Edit:

Here is what I'm trying to achieve.

```
{% flag = false %}
{% for row in results %}
    {{ row.field }}
    {% if row.is_active and !flag %}
        <br />
        {% flag = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is a bit vague.  Think you could show us some example code?

Comment: django documention provides examples on how to use conditionals and loops in templates https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/

Comment: I've included some code to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to do one thing with the first part of the QuerySet, and other thing with the rest. Split it in the view.

**views.py**

```
def split_list(list, condition):
    list1, list2 = [], []
    condition_satisfied = False
    for element in list:
        if not condition_satisfied and condition(element):
            condition_satisfied = True
        if not condition_satisfied:
            list1.append(element)
        else:
            list2.append(element)
    return list1, list2

def your_view(request):
    results = YourModel.objects.all()
    results1, results2 = split_list(results, condition)
    return render(request, 'template.html', {
        'results1': results1,
        'results2': results2
    })
```

**template.html**

```
{% for result in results1 %}
    {% if result == whatever %}
        <p>Condition satisfied</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Condition not satisfied</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% for result in results2 %}
    {{ result }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't have this feature, and for good reason. Templates should not contain this kind of logic. It should be done within the View.

Comment: I'm new to django and I'm trying to learn the right way of doing things.  I'm laying out what I'm trying to do and hoping someone is able to help me.